# Parallel route sharing with Dynamic route in NextJS v14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I've a route directory `/products`. Now in products `layout.tsx` I've JSX structure like below

`products/layout.tsx`

```
<section className="section py-16">
  <div className="grid grid-cols-12 space-x-4">
    <div className="col-span-3">{props.filters}</div>
    <div className="col-span-9">{props.children}</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In above;

1. `props.filters` is a slot
2. `props.children` is products `page.tsx` component

#### Directory Structure

```js
products
-@filters
--page.tsx
layout.tsx (products layout)
page.tsx (products page)
```

### Requirements

I need to create a product details page. So I've created with my structure

```js
products
-[productName]
--page.tsx (product details page)
-@filters
--page.tsx
layout.tsx (products layout)
page.tsx (products page)
```

Now in `products/laptop`. I see the `@filters` slot elements on both `/products` & `products/laptop` route but it should be only in `/products`.

1. I also tried by creating a new `layout.tsx` in `[productName]` directory. No solution
2. I can do this without creating a slot `@filters`. But for individually render I've create this

How to achieve my requirements?